# Why Ruby's Pessimistic Operator is named pessimistic?

Tags: rubygems

I started to learn Ruby on Rails, and found

> ~>

in Gemfile. I found

> '~> 3.0.3'

means `>= 3.03` and `< 3.1`

but Does someone know why this operator is named Pessimistic? Pessimistic is word of emotion, and I'm not pessimistic to use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there is an optimistic way to specify it:

```
'>= 2.2.2'
```

and that means anything greater than `2.2.2`, even `7.0`.  Now that may be too optimistic, because usually, 7.0 may not be compatible with your existing code already -- we want to just say "give me the version that is supposedly backward compatible", and it is

```
'~> 2.2'
```

and that means, `'>= 2.2'` but `< 3.0`, meaning `2.8.123` is still ok, but not `3.0` or above, because `3.0` supposedly has major updates and may not be backward compatible with your code.  So you are being a little bit pessimistic, and hence the name "pessimistic operator".

Reference: [Pessimistic version constraint](https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint), [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/).

Comment: Thank you for answering, makes sense to me.
To do major update automatically is "optimistic", and to prevent it is "pessimistic" compared to that.

Comment: Now, why is the same thing named [optimistic operator](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#specifying-pod-versions) in CocoaPods?

Comment: this is a funny question. I am not entirely sure, but maybe we can view it this way: saying we can use 2.x but not 3.0 is a pretty positive action. It follows semantic versioning that it makes sense. So we can say, it is a positive action, and call it optimistic. On the other hand, saying `>= 2.0.0` can mean all the way to 7.0. So if your perspective is: that is likely not to work; why are you stating it this way, and it is almost like if you know it is not going to work but you state it this way anyway, you are giving it up, and we call it pessimistic. So it just depends on perspectives

Comment: yeah, i guess it's just the point of view. `~> 2.2` is optimistic compared to `= 2.2` but pessimistic compared to `>= 2.2`